# HtmlTextWriter write new line not working

Tags: c#

I am building a Webpart and I am running into a problem with the HtmlTextWriter

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        base.RenderContents(writer);
        foreach (var item in list)
            {
                //These i have tried;
                writer.Write(string.Format(item.Text + " {0}", Environment.NewLine));
                writer.Write(item.Text + " \n");
                writer.Write(item.Text + " \r\n");
                writer.Write(item.Text + " \n\r");
            }
    }
```

I have tried the code above, but what is the problem because it does not make a line break ?

Comment: You don't know HTML? ;-) It's `<br />`

Comment: Your code will add line break if you VIEW SOURCE, if you want on HTML line break see Tim's comment of <br />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    base.RenderContents(writer);
    foreach (var item in list)
        {
            writer.Write(item.Text + "<br/>");
        }
}
```

or this if you want to have an unordered list

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    base.RenderContents(writer);
    if (list.Any())
    {
        writer.Write("<ul>");
        foreach (var item in list)
            {
                writer.Write("<li>" + item.Text + "</li>");
            }
        writer.Write("</ul>");
    }
}
```